# Adding checkbox in markdown table does not work

Tags: git, github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I am trying to create a markdown table where one of the column should have a checkbox.

I have tried the following:

```
| Db2WoC Plan                                 | Total time | RPO,RTO met | 
| ------------------------------------------- |  --------- |-------------|
| Db2 on Cloud Entry/Enterprise 1 TB          |  8:10:16   |  <ul><li>[x] item1</li><li>[ ] item2</li></ul>   |  
| Db2 Warehouse on Cloud for transaction      |  8:10:16   | - [x] ok    |
| Db2 Warehouse on Cloud(AWS)                 |  8:10:16   | - [x] ok    |
| Db2 Warehouse on Cloud(Softlayer)           |  8:10:16   | - [x] ok    |
```

But none of this work.

I see the following as a result:

```
Db2WoC Plan Total time  RPO,RTO met
Db2 on Cloud Entry/Enterprise 1 TB  8:10:16 [x] item1
                                            [ ] item2
Db2 Warehouse on Cloud for transaction  8:10:16 - [x] ok
Db2 Warehouse on Cloud(AWS) 8:10:16 - [x] ok
Db2 Warehouse on Cloud(Softlayer)   8:10:16 - [x] ok
```

The table shown in https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pchaigno/1826ba1151890b751862/raw/73399cc5a5d2415e2a75f58fd6959d25770c4ed3/checkboxes.md does not work as well.

Answer (score 15):

Use an HTML entity (`&check;`) or an emoji (`:heavy_check_mark:`).

The GitHub Markdown Spec specifically [states](https://github.github.com/gfm/#tables-extension-):

> Block-level elements cannot be inserted in a table.

List items are block level elements and are therefore not permitted within table cells. And [task list items](https://github.github.com/gfm/#task-list-items-extension-) are simply another style of list item that happens to contain a checkbox. It you don't have a list item, then you can't have a task list item. In other words, you can not have task list items within table cells.

As the original Markdown rules [explain](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself.

And, as a HTML checkbox would be an inline element, one might be tempted to insert a raw HTML [checkbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox) directly into a table cell:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked>
```

However, there is the issue that GitHub's sanitation filter will remove the checkbox. In fact, GitHub's task lists doesn't use actual checkbox elements, but images of checkmarks.

A more useful option might be to use an [HTML entity](https://www.webfx.com/tools/emoji-cheat-sheet/) or [emoji](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/ballot%20box) for a checkmark.  For example:

```
| Description                         | Checkmark               |
| ----------------------------------- | ----------------------- |
| HTML Entity: check mark             | &check;                 |
| HTML Entity: heavy check mark       | &#10004;                |
| HTML Entity: ballot box with check  | &#9745;                 |
| HTML Entity: ballot box with x      | &#9746;                 |
| HTML Entity: ballot box (unchecked) | &#9744;                 |
| Emoji: heavy check mark             | :heavy_check_mark:      |
| Emoji: ballot box with check        | :ballot_box_with_check: |
| Emoji: white check mark             | :white_check_mark:      |
```

As you are using table cells, you probably don't need an unchecked box, the empty table cell will suffice. However, if you really want empty checkbox as well, the [ballot box](http://www.amp-what.com/unicode/search/ballot%20box) should work well for that.

I've added a [comment](https://gist.github.com/pchaigno/1826ba1151890b751862/#gistcomment-2837082) to your gist which demonstrates what all of the above options look like on GitHub.